# Laravel API resourceCollection using array rather than model

Tags: laravel, rest

I have an API that uses API resource and resource collections to correctly format the JSON responses. In order to decouple my controller from my model I use an adapter to query the underlying model. I'd like to pass the adapter return values as arrays, rather than Eloquent models, to ensure that any furture adapters are easier to right in respect to their return data structures. To create the array return values I serialise my adapter Eloquent results with ->toArray().

I have 2 API Resources to correctly format these results, for a single resource I have:

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\Resource;

```
class Todo extends Resource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return $this->resource;
    }
}
```

For a resource collection I have:

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\ResourceCollection;

```
class TodoCollection extends ResourceCollection
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource collection into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'data' => $this->collection
                          ->map
                          ->toArray($request)
                          ->all()
        ];
    }
}
```

When I return a single resource from my controller with :

```
use App\Http\Resources\Todo;

public function show($id)
{
    return new Todo($this->todoAdapter->findById($id));
}
```

and the adapter query as:

```
public function findById(int $id){
        return TodoModel::findOrFail($id)
                ->toArray();
}
```

This works as expected. The problem comes when I try to pass an array of a collection of models i.e.

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $todos = $this->todoAdapter->getAllForUserId(Auth::id(), 'created_by', 'desc', self::DEFAULT_PAGINATE);
    return new TodoCollection($todos);
}
```

and the adapter query as:

```
public function getAllForUserId(int $userId, string $sortField, string $sortDir, int $pageSize = self::DEFAULT_PAGINATE)
{
        return Todo::BelongsUser($userId)
                                    ->orderBy($sortField, $sortDir)
                                    ->paginate($pageSize)
                                    ->toArray();
}
```

I get the following error:

```
"message": "Call to a member function first() on array",
    "exception": "Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError",
    "file": "/home/vagrant/code/public/umotif/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Resources/CollectsResources.php",
    "line": 24,
```

I'm guessing that I can't do 'new TodoCollection($todos)' where $todos is an array of results. How would I get my todoCollection to work with arrays? Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Comment: you could have make this much simplier than this

Comment: In what way do you mean?

Comment: you could have passed collection object in your resource and make it an array there as laravel documentation says

Comment: How would I do that in the resource? Isn't the point of returning an array from the adapter to make it easier to implement other adapters? For example if I'm getting data via an API adapter then I won't need to convert that to a collection if the resource expects an array?

Comment: please have a look https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-resources#introduction, it says ` Laravel's resource classes allow you to expressively and easily transform your models and model collections into JSON.`

Comment: Yes, checked that, I want to use resource and resource collections to take arrays rather than models. I want to do this in case I have a situation where I replace the eloquent models with another data source. Perhaps I'm missing the point?

Comment: ow!! got your point, thanks for clarification

Comment: No problem, thanks for your input. Would be great to find out how to pass an array to a resource collection!

Answer (score 0):

Your collections toArray is trying to do too much:

```
$this->collection
         ->map
         ->toArray($request)
         ->all()
```

Just directly call `$this->collection->toArray()`.

Comment: Tried to replace collections toArray() with return $this->collection->toArray(); but get the same error - thanks for your suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

Just to update this. In the end I found that creating a collection from the array of results and passing that to the resource collection constructor worked, though I did have to add explicit mappings within the resource collection for links and meta etc.

Comment: Hi Can you tell me how to retrieve multi array items in the response object in TodoResource file. my $this->response is like 
array(25) {
  [0]=>
  array(9) {
    ["ID"]=>
    int(3160)
    ["UserID"]=>
    int(3302)
    ["ItemName"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["Description"]=>
    string(1) "2" } }

Comment: In the Resource I just added the following to the toArray() method - return $this->resource; If your working with a collection (i.e. ResourceCollection) then convert to an array first ($collectionArray = $this->collection->toArray();), then get the bits you need e.g. return [
            'data' => $this->collection->get('data')];